# Wrapping stuff with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to get some list elements inside of wrapper div/span. This is how it is now:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

What I need is something like this:

```
<ul>
<div class="wrapper">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</div><div class="wrapper">
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</div><div class="wrapper">
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
<div class="wrapper">
</ul>
```

Or that  can be somthing like span. Doesnt really matter. BUt I need to wrap after every three li elements.

Comment: That's not valid HTML - `li` list items are the only thing `ul` unordered lists can contain. If you need multicolumn lists have you considered using floats or CSS3 Columns instead?

Comment: output you are expecting is not a valid HTML. It is not recommended to have such HTML in your page

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your elements and wrap them using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), like this:

```
var lis = $("ul li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=3) {
  lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<li class="wrapper"><ul></ul></li>');
}
```

Since you said something *like* a `<div>`/`<span>` this will do the job, and give you valid HTML, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your example showed every 2 elements, but your question text said every 3...I just picked 3 here, just adjust the number in the function and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid HTML and it is wrong to do it - You cannot insert div inside list, but I will give for future reference the syntax of wrapping in jQuery:

```
$("JQUERYSELECTOR").wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
```

The JQUERYSELECTOR should be whatever elements that you want to wrap i.e

```
#ul:nth-child(1)
```

for the first child of the list.

But again, wrapping div on list items is wrong.